# loop through a set of elements and animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I've got a set of elements where when I click on a specific button, I want to animate one element at a time using jquery.

This is my html markup.

```
<ul class="image-wrapper">
                <li class="image">
                    <img src="images/slider-image-1.jpg">
                </li>
                <li class="image">
                    <img src="images/slider-image-1.jpg">
                </li>
                <li class="image">
                    <img src="images/slider-image-1.jpg">
                </li>
            </ul>

            <div class="left-arrow"></div>
            <div class="right-arrow"></div>
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <div class="menu"></div>
```

This is my jquery code for animate each element.

```
$('.left-arrow').click(function(){
        $('.image').first().animate({
            width:'0px'
        },1000);
    })
```

But the problem is after the first animation, I cannot continue with the rest! how can I loop through the elements to slide in each element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to keep and index

```
var index = 0, $imgs = $('.image');
$('.left-arrow').click(function(){
    $imgs.eq(index ).animate({
        width:'0px'
    },1000);
    index = index == 0 ? $imgs.length - 1  : index - 1 ;
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PWHuZ/)

Answer (score 0):

Try jquery's [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/),

```
$('.left-arrow').click(function(){
        $('.image').each(function(){
          $(this).animate({
            width:'0px'
        },1000);
    })
```